.NET MAUI Blazor How to prevent iOS keyboard from pushing up the entire screen when focus on textarea?
I know this is a very old question but I have tried many solutions and it did not work on .NET Maui Blazor. I just dont want the view to go up or move when ios keyboard shows up when focusing on a textarea.
This is the solution that I have tried.
How to prevent iOS keyboard from pushing the view off screen with CSS or JS

Although the solution provided in the link will work with .NET MAUI Blazor with proper implementation. It just scroll's to the top of the page. If that's what you want, you can implement like below.
Add the script to Index.html like below
<script>
        window.OnInputFocused = function () {
            window.scrollTo(0,0)
            document.body.scrollTop = 0
        } 

</script>

Now in you razor component subscribe to onfocus of textarea and invoke the script like below
@page "/"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<div style="height: 50vh;">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>
Welcome to your new app.
<textarea @onfocus="Test" />
@code
{
    private async Task Test()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("OnInputFocused");
    }
 }


